# VS 2019 C# update customer mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have written an C# winforms app and I have bound a MySQL database on it.

The customer also get a copy of the database on his site.

If I do some changes in the structure of my database and want to make the same changes in the customer database as well as part of a setup or something. How can I do this in best practice?

Comment: you mean changes to the structure? At the simplest you can ensure you generate SQL scripts of all the changes you make (unless you're doing it via Entity Framework Code First - you didn't mention??), which you can then re-use on the other database to make the same changes. Ensure you source-control the scripts then you have a record of it and the ability to reproduce them in other environments. Of course if the changes impact on data (e.g. you have to move data, or delete it, or add new data as part of the change) then it gets a bit more complex.

Comment: You need to store all your database "change scripts" (that update the schema) and determine which ones haven't been applied yet, then apply those when new code is delivered. https://flywaydb.org/ is a project that can do this.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is a Web API that acts like a layer of abstraction over a single database. And multiple clients (desktop, web) can access it without having to change or update it multiple times.